# Radio buttons to real-time interact with the database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I would like to get some help on my coding, I am struggling to get the radio buttons connecting to MySQL database.

What it is that I want is so that when someone clicks either 'yes' or 'no' on the radio buttons it automatically stores in the MySQL database, I have had a look at various other ways that I can do it but I can't get it to work. Below is a screenshot.

[image: image here]

Comment: First of all your code program doesn't matter, you should probably remove it from your title. The second thing if I understand your right you wanna have a live interact with the database when the user click on the radio??

Comment: yes i want it to store automatically into the database once clicked on

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LGSon I think he/she ask for what to look for to get that function. in this case, it's Ajax

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor Question posters still need to include reasonable explanation and a code sample, which is not done here, and _an image with the code_ is not good enough

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, You want to store the radio value in MySQL. There's no such thing as "store it in PMA". You can store the value in MySQL, but you can't without using php. (Your current code is only HTML)

With PHP & MySQL, you could do something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO mytablename(checkbox_value) VALUES("' . $_POST['gen1'] . '")';
```

`$_POST['gen1']` could return the selected value (e.g.: "yes"), and `checkbox_value` could be enum and only contain "yes" and "no" values.

If you're looking to insert these values into MySQL, Consider learning about [INSERT INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) in MySQL Documentation. Also, learn about [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) HTTP variable.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna make a real-time interaction with the database you need to more than just HTML, in fact, you need 2 extra languages to do that, so lets us begin.

---

#### The HTML

First of all, you have your HTML5 form it could e.g look like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="0"> Man
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="1"> Women
</form>
```

*important thing about this!* The `<form>` we don't give it a method after some we don't need it when using jQuery/Ajax to communicate with the backend

---

#### Real-time interact (by using Ajax)

include the jQuery library and link to it with `<script src="jQuery.min.js"></script>`

Right before your `</body>` tag includes this code, it looks for if any radio bottoms have changed and if that true then it looks for the value of input named "sex" and store it in a variable called value.

We send the value as a POST named sex, so in *db.php* it will look like a `$_POST['sex']`

```
<script>
    $(":radio").change(function() {
        var value = $('input[name=sex]:checked').val();

        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'db.php', 
            data: { 
                sex: value 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

#### The PHP (backend)

Now we just need to grab the data and run a query to get it into the database.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sex'])
    {
        $sex = htmlspecialchars($_POST['sex']);
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO mytablename(checkbox_value) VALUES("{$sex}")';

    }
?>
```

You will need to make a connection to the database first, [see here how](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp). I will recommend that you use prepare statements, they are not so funny to work within standard MySQLi connection so when you fill that you know what you are doing so begin to use a PDO connect [Connect with PDO](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

> **Note:** I do not have tested this code before post it. But in any way, it should lead you in the right direction.